What is the relation between the uniformity of nature and determinism?
I read about Hume's argument that the uniformity of nature is a necessary condition for inductive reasoning to be valid, but we only have inductive reasons for believing in the uniformity in the first place.
As far as I can tell, Uniformity of Nature means that events taking place with the same initial conditions will produce the same results. This sounds an awful lot like determinism. Since all conditions globally can never be same for two events occuring at different times, I should also think that locality is another condition for uniformity.
So I'm wondering whether determinism and/or locality is necessary or equivalent to uniformity of nature, and consequently also what the consequences of quantum phenomena and the Bell's paradox are for inductive reasoning.
Sorry if my question is a bit unorganized, since I don't know much about the matter. Some reading material to get better aquainted with these concepts would also be welcome.
Edit: Note here that I am referring to the scientific notion of determinism, rather than the more abstract problem of free will.

While uniformity is physical (trees falling always cause noise), determinism is moreover metaphysical: the fact that I decide to raise my arm and then raise it can be predetermined (my brain just follows a predetermined causal chain of reactions, so I don't change the future) or can be non-deterministic (I am, in fact, able to change the future).

There is no relation, you can have either one without the other. Hume's formulation is "instances, of which we have had no experience, must resemble those, of which we have had experience", often shortened to "future must resemble the past" or "when similar situations recur, similar effects follow". Essentially, laws governing events, deterministic or not, should stay fixed. If past situations were indeterministic, say, then they should remain so in the future. Conversely, if deterministic laws change every hour then the nature will be deterministic but not uniform.

@Conifold, How can you have uniformity without any determinism? (Seems at least inanimate matter would need to behave deterministically for physical events to happen as described by natural laws).

Uniformity of Nature means that events taking place with the same initial conditions will produce the same results. - I think you can have slightly weakened flavours of 'uniformity of nature' which aren't quite so tightly-bound to exactly the same results. Quantum Mechanics suggests a uniformity which is a bit more loose. For example, in quantum mechanics, it's not the exact result of any single event that will be exactly the same with the same starting conditions, but the probability distribution of results will be the same if you take many samples. It's a probabilistic uniformity.

@tkruse Random coin flips are uniform as long as the probability of heads and tails stays fixed. Past does not have to determine the future, however much (or little) it constrains it just has to be uniform in time.

"Something remains uniform" is a very weak uniformity. Like "the distribution changes, but the duration the coins stays in the air remains same, so it's still a bit uniform" seems to not follow the spirit of uniformity of nature, so not sure why you would allow for only the distribution to remain the same.

@tkruse The 'spirit' of "uniformity of nature" is trivially false anyway. The future clearly does not "resemble" the past in every respect, and we have no non-circular way of specifying respects that it is supposed to "resemble". This is why the uniformity 'principle' has no cogent formulations and the problem of induction is so notorious.


I read about Hume's argument that the uniformity
of nature is a necessary condition for inductive
reasoning to be valid, but we only have inductive
reasons for believing in the uniformity in the first place.

I think you have misread it: in the context of the (philosophical)
"problem of induction", "the uniformity of nature" and "the validity of
inductive reasoning" are equivalent formulations of the same postulate.
The "problem of induction" is about (the necessity of) the validity
of formulating laws, of thought and of nature, and, more generally,
the validity of reasoning from the perceived (concrete and/or particular)
to the unperceived (abstract and/or general).
Note: the validity of inductive reasoning is essential to (the validity
of) all our endeavours, including to (the validity of) deductive
reasoning, which is subordinate.  Notice in particular that here
"induction" is not induction as in mathematical or formal logic, these
rather being instances of deductive reasoning.
See these articles for more context and details:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/
https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~jim/williams.pdf

As far as I can tell, Uniformity of Nature means
that events taking place with the same initial
conditions will produce the same results. This
sounds an awful lot like determinism.

As said, that is not what "the uniformity of nature" means.  That is
in fact the physics notion of determinism, not even the philosophical
notion and "problem of determinism", which is determinism vs free will.

what the consequences of quantum phenomena and the Bell's
paradox are for inductive reasoning.

As it should now be obvious, none, rather the opposite: it is only
by postulating the "validity of induction" that we get to formulate
any laws at all, mathematical or physical, quantum or otherwise.
OTOH, whether "quantum" has any import on "determinism vs free fill"
remains quite speculative at this point...
